# Cookie in Javascript or JQuery for GDPR

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have limited experience with Javascript/JQuery outside of HTML/CSS 'animations'.

I have a website that does NOT use cookies and I have a banner that displays on page load a statement to that effect. Obviously this appears every time the page loads.

I would like to set a cookie via an 'OK' button/link for say 60 days that is read on page load and if positive doesn't display that cookie banner.

I've been searching the internet but I'm struggling to find what I believe should be a simple thing to implement if you know how.

I'm also unsure whether to use 'just' Javascript or a library (JQuery) to implement this.

Conceptually I think I need something like this:

On page load, look for the cookie, if positive value, do not display the cookie banner, else display the cookie banner. The 'OK' button on the cookie banner, creates the cookie with a positive value. The cookie will expire in 60 days.

It's the syntax I'm struggling with. Can anyone help please?

Comment: What about using local storage instead of cookie? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp You can store date and time into a local variable (string) when button is pressed and in case date in this variable is > 60 days or there is no local variable set, you show your banner. I find it easier than cookies in JS but in case you wanna stick to cookies have a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.

Comment: Hi Kaya, thanks for you comment - I haven't used web storage before but after reading about it, it seems like a good solution. Again it's the syntax I'm struggling with, are you able to provide any for what I want to achieve? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The functions needed = Just copy paste this in your js file we only need them to add and read cookies.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/; sameSite=Strict";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Here is the part where you need to understand a bit of what is happening.

To set a cookie you add this line

setCookie("cookieConsent", "YES", 60);

This call the function copy pasted from earlier and set a cookie with the name cookieConsent and the value YES. The number 60 is how many days the cookies should store.

So if you can pinpoint the place where you need to set the cookie, then just copy paste that code in there.

Reading said cookie.
We can always check if a user has the cookies by this

```
if(getCookie("cookieConsent") === "YES"){
    console.log("They said already said yes, dont show banner")
}
```

The line with console.log(), can be replaced with whatever desired function you wish to use.

Comment: Hi Preben, thank you for replying. All of that syntax is what I am struggling with, as I just do not have enough experience with Javascript. I think I need to do a course or something. Regards.

Comment: I will breakt it down for you. and update my reply.

Comment: Thank you Preben, this helps a lot, I'm grateful for your patience.